# tell me please why in beamer not \bf not \textbf don't work?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian,russian]{babel}
%\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage{ textcomp }
\usepackage{ eqnarray }
\usepackage{ txfonts }
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{Відповіді на питання у форматі презентації}
 \logo{
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{1590609722363.png}
    \hspace{0.1cm}
     } 
\author{...}

\begin{document}% начало презентации
\begin{frame}% первый слайд
\titlepage{}
\end{frame}



{
\title{\textcolor{orange}{Питання №1}}
\usebackgroundtemplate{ \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{?.jpg} }
\begin{frame}% второй слайд

        \large\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Питання №1:}}
        \\Назвіть основні стандартні технологічні процеси виготовлення  електронних і механічних компонентів та вузлів \textbf{\underline{мікросистемної}} техніки. 
           Назвіть основні специфічні технологічні процеси.
\end{frame}
}



{
\title{\textcolor{orange}{Головні визначення}}
\usebackgroundtemplate{ \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{s.jpg} }
\begin{frame}
\center{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{А щож таке мікросистема та технологія її виготовлення?}}\\

\textbf
     {
      \largeЦе інтегрована інформаційно-керуюча система, функціонально і структурно об'єднана для збору і обробки інформації в 
          реальному масштабі часу і подальшого вироблення впливів на виконавчі елементи або об'єкт управління.\\
          Мікросистемна технологія: послідовність технологічних операцій групової мікрообробки поверхні матеріалу заготовки з метою виготовлення, складання, корпусування і 
          вимірювання елементів, компонентів і вузлів мікросистеми.
          }
\end{frame}
}



{
\title{\textcolor{orange}{Основні види технології}}
\usebackgroundtemplate{ \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{f.jpg} }
\begin{frame}
\center{\fcolorbox{black}{green}{Базові технології мікро- і наносистемної техніки}}\\
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2pt}\doublerulesepcolor{yellow}
\begin {center}
\begin{tabular}{||c||c||c||c||}
\hhline{|t:=:t:=:t:=t:=:t|}
\textcolor{orange}{EFAB} & \textcolor{green}{LIGA}& \textcolor{cyan}{SUMMiT} & \textcolor{magenta}{МUMPs}\\
\hhline{|b:=:b:=:b:=b:=:b|}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
}
```

Comment: I think the Unicode №1 creates the problem. Did you compile in XeLaTeX?

Comment: I have just tried to compile my code in XeLaTeX and there were not any letters only ",   .    ' ; ,   , .    , ;   " just like this. (I just started to work with LaTex) may be I do not understand  something?

Comment: The length of non-compilable code is inversely proportional to the hope that someone has the desire of debug it. Start making a minimal compilable presentation (e.g.: `\documentclass{beamer}\begin{document}\begin{frame} Hi \end{frame}\end{document}`) and then add the minimal preamble, the minimal frames and the minimal content to reproduce your problem, but only this problem and no others, as, for instance, left the code without  `\end{document}`  !